# I am trying to create a function for a calculator. I want the program to try to parse a string given to transform it to an double number

Tags: c#, function, exception, double

I am trying to create a function for a calculator. I want the program to try to parse a string given to transform it to an double number. My function has the following form:

```
private double readOperator(String stringOper) 
  {
        try
        {
            double oper;
            oper = double.Parse(stringOper);
            return oper;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Input");
            throw ex; // Without this I have to return a double value (no null allowed)
        }
  }
```

**PROBLEM**: I need the function to return a double value so to be able to access it on from the main program as a double. But if the parsing fails (it has chars inside) the only way to get buy the debuger is to either return a double value (not good as the user must be able to input whatever double value he wishes) or to throw an exception which freezes the program.

I don't really need any kind of handling instead of informing the user to change his input, as it is a form. But by throwing the exception the program crashes (as it should). If I continue to run the program by allowing Windows to do so when they ask me everything runs as I want to run. But obviously I don't want the user to go through this process!

**Solution**: how can I handle the throwing of this exception not to crash the program (to do nothing at all) or how could I return a null/special type of value to handle this? Using public variables is not a good programming method which can easily solve this issue

Comment: Use `TryParse()` and return a nullable double (`double?`). That way no exception handling is needed. Or just handle the exception outside `readOperator`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Well, I study on my own :) :) How can I handle it outside the function?? This is what I am trying to find out.. I believe I had done this in Java but I can't recall how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So handle it (to inform user is handling the exception) in main method:

```
static void main()
{
    try
    {
       Console.Write("Enter first operand: ");
       double a = readOperand(Console.ReadLine());

       Console.Write("Enter second operand: ");
       double b = readOperand(Console.ReadLine());

       // Do something with them
    }
   catch (FormatException)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a floating point number.");
   }
}
```

Or, better, do not even throw exceptions (it's a good practice if you can avoid them: invalid user input isn't an exceptional situation):

```
double a;
if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a floating point number.");
```

In case your input validation is something more (for example range checking too) than a `Double.TryParse()` (and you want to keep it in a separate function) then you have two options:

- return a nullable value (`double?` in this case) where `null` means *invalid input*.
- mimic `TryParse` behavior and prototype: `bool TryReadOperand(string operand, out double value)`. Simply return `false` for invalid inputs (decide where to output error message, I would suggest `Main` because it's more common).

Comment: Oh! That's so sweet.. Exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks a lot :) :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Secondly the simplest solution is to return `double?` from your method, and interpret `null` as parsing failure. However in general returning `null` as a "special value" is not considered a good design.

Why not just throw an exception (like you do now), and catch and handle it in a place when you call `readOperator` method?

Comment: Null is not acceptable as a return double value (at least in C#). Thanks though

Comment: @GiannhsGiannis That's why I've said to change the method to return `double?`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two options.

1. Try catch around every instance of readOperator() and handle the invalid input in that catch statement.
2. change it to `private double? readOperator(string stringOper)`. double? is double that allows null values so it would be fine to `return null`.

The following transforms a nullable double into a normal one

```
//where d is a double?
if (d.HasValue) //Returns true if not null
{
    double x = d.Value // Returns the double value of the double? if not null otherwise throws exception
}
else
{
    // Handle the null value
}
```

edit: Kind of duped another user's answer while writing but I'm going to leave mine here for the example

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but this is not what I was asking for (i mention this about the duped answer). My issue is not the parsing, but the exception handling without having to return a value.. A fellow above showed me how to double handle exception. Thanks though :):)

Comment: Ah okay well that is what option 1 was but you're right I didn't provide an example for that. Thanks for responding to this though I always like to know if I helped or not.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse is a good bet:

```
    private double readOperator(String stringOper)
    {
        double oper;

        if (Double.TryParse(stringOper, out oper))
            return oper;

        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Input");
        return 0;
    }
```

Also, when you throw an exception using throw ex; you're losing your stack trace.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Input");
    throw; // <---- retains stack trace
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Pretty good solution for the specific issue, totally works with fewer code! I'll keep it in mind for parsing from now on. But I was looking for the general external exception handling which @Adriano gave above.. Thanks a lot guys :D :D